# How to get particular row button title in UITableView button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Creating timetable for school, Implemented the design using UITableView [image]

2 days and 6 periods, periods is dynamic it can show n numbers.

My code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dayArr.count-1
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:PeriodCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PeriodCell") as! PeriodCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    var x: Int = 2
    for i in 0 ..< periodArr.count
    {
            let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: 110, height: 45))
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            btn.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
            btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            btn.tag = indexPath.row
            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
            btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            cell.contentView.addSubview(btn)
            x = x + 115
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

My button click action:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let btnsendtag: UIButton = sender
        print("btnsendtag",btnsendtag.tag)
        sender.setTitle("Tamil",for: .normal)
        for i in 0 ..< periodArr.count
        {
            print("btnsendtag",btnsendtag.tag)
            if let buttonTitle = btnsendtag.title(for: .normal)
            {
                print("buttonTitle",buttonTitle)
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem:
1. I want to get each button title. Monday and Tuesday separate as array separate and send to webservices [or] get the all button title and send it comma separate to webservices .[periods is dynamic it can show n numbers] want to get all title. Day only 6 days always shown.

2. How to identify which button is selected, which button value is adding and without selected button want to send empty title to webservies. How can identify.

How to write the code for button click action. Please help me, I am struggling on this from a week. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for header item concept to archive this in collection view easily for the table view it's really hard to get this type of thing what you are asking for.

Comment: Do u know how to implement in collectionview give any example source to please

Comment: Please share ur mail id I will share the demo code.

Comment: saravananesec@gmail.com

Comment: hello ru there?\

Comment: yeah please check your mail id after 10 mins.